# Flexbox Image Grid Layout

Tags: html, css, grid, flexbox

maybe some of you can help me with my problem. 
I need to implement a Flexbox Image Grid.

What I've done is, to use a simple Flexbox Grid with Images in Flex-items.
My Problem are not the images or the Flex-System as usual, but the order of these Flex-Items.

Here is a simple Screenshot of what I've to create:
http://prntscr.com/ebk00f

My main problem is to get the last image on the Position after these two smaller images, maybe someone can help me out here?

And here I am at the moment:

```css
.flex-col {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.story-teaser-container .story-block {
width: 25%;
flex: 25%;
}
.story-teaser-container .story-block.story-item-1 {
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
flex: 50%;
}
.story-teaser-container .story-block.story-item-4 {
width: 50%;
flex: 0 1 50%;
align-self: flex-end;
}
.story-teaser-container .story-image-holder {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
display: block;
}
.story-teaser-container .story-image-holder .story-image {
line-height: 0;
}
.story-teaser-container .story-image-holder .story-image img {
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="story-teaser-container">
    <div class="flex-col">
        <div class="image story-item-1 story-block">
            <a href="#" class="story-image-holder">
                <div class="story-image">
                    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=1061">
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="image story-item-2 story-block">
            <a href="#" class="story-image-holder">
                <div class="story-image">
                    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=1013">
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="image story-item-3 story-block">
            <a href="#" class="story-image-holder">
                <div class="story-image">
                    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=1023">
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="image story-item-4 story-block">
            <a href="#" class="story-image-holder">
                <div class="story-image">
                    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=1043">
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This might be a situation where floating the images is better suited. Check out this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k5ztfaL5/

Comment: @PaulAllen Yeah i was thinking about that and it solves my problem that the images are in the right order - but i need to make the left big image the equal height as the opposite group of images and thats not possible without the flexbox items. :(

Comment: What explicitly are you looking for with your end result? I don't quite understand what you mean by the position for the last image.